# Property of universal enveloping algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a finite dimensional complex Lie algebra and $U(L)$ be its universal enveloping algebra.

If $A$ is an associateive algebra with $1$ such that

- $L$ is a subspace of $A$
- $A$ is generated (as algebra) by $L$,
- for all $x,y\in L$, the relation $[x,y]=xy-yx$ holds in $A$,

then is it true that $A$ can be *embedded* in $U(L)$?

I think this is true by applying universal property of $U(L)$.

I am trying to see whether $U(L)$ is the *largest* (in this sense) associative algebra w.r.t. above three properties.

Comment: The universal property goes the co-direction you think it does: you would expect nice algebras $A$ to be realised as *quotients* of the universal enveloping algebra $U(L)$, not as subalgebras.